# How to set up a one-step transition matrix

Tags: probability, matrices, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I figured out:

you step up a level if you roll a six this has a probability $ p = \frac{1}{6}$

you fall back to level zero if you roll an odd number this has probability $ p = \frac{1}{2}$

otherwise you stay at the same level (this is if you roll 2, 4) so this has probability $p =\frac{1}{3}$

Because we do not know the end of the game I am struggling how to form a one step probability matrix, any help appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The states are the levels, which according to your description can be all nonnegative integers.  So it's going to be an infinite transition matrix, but that's OK.  The entry for row $i$, column $j$ is the probability to go from state $i$ to state $j$.  If $i > 0$ this is $1/6$ for $j=i+1$, $1/2$ for $j=0$, $1/3$ for $j=i$, otherwise $0$.  You have to modify this slightly for $i=0$, as "stay the same" and "go to $0$" are the same, so $P_{0,0}=5/6$,
$P_{0,1}=1/6$, $P_{0,j}=0$ otherwise.

Comment: The first row is $i=0$, and the first column is $j=0$.  The row labels the state you are coming from, the column is the state you're going to.  Conventions may differ: some people may do it the other way.